# Sending data from activity to a fragment?

Tags: java, android

I have AddMembers.class activity and MembersFragment.class fragment. I have been trying to send my data from AddMembers to MembersFragment, as through logging I confirmed that my data is set correctly by using setArguments() method but while retrieving the data I am getting null value.

So can anyone tell me that why am I getting null value when I call getArguments() method in the fragment.

Thanks in advance!

Here's my AddMembers.class src-code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_members);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    final String members_name = intent.getStringExtra("tripName");

    TextView membersTextView = findViewById(R.id.membersTextView);
    final EditText membersEditText = findViewById(R.id.membersEditText);
    Button addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AddMembers.this, HomePage.class);
            String names = String.valueOf(membersEditText.getText());

            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            MembersFragment membersFragment = new MembersFragment();

            startActivity(intent);

            data.putString("name", names);
            membersFragment.setArguments(data);
        }
    });
}
```

}

and this is my MembersFragment.class src-code:

```
private MembersViewModel membersViewModel;
String mParam;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
    membersViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MembersViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_members, container, false);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam = getArguments().getString("name");
    }

    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_members);
    membersViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not use startActivity when destination is fragment, in AddMembers activity insert this code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", "From Activity");
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and try get sent data in MembersFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("name");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the data to the intent before calling `startActivity()`

```
intent.putExtra(key, value);
```

And you get the value by then calling

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you:
AddMembers.class

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", membersEditText.getText().toString());

MembersFragment frag = new MembersFragment();
frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

MembersFragment.class

```
    String name = getArguments().getString("name");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
```